# How can I detect by static analysis, if a project is using Java8?

Tags: java, syntax, java-8, abstract-syntax-tree

I am currently using javaparser (https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) and javasymbolsolver(https://github.com/javaparser/javasymbolsolver), to parse through the code. Will it be a holistic approach if I detect the usage of Collections#Streams, to decide that the particular project has migrated to Java8.(Assuming that Collection#Streams is the most widely used java8 feature).

Comment: The simplest way would be to try to build it with `-source 1.7`.

Comment: You need to decide what you want to detect. Dependency on Java 8 APIs or usage of Java 8 language features.

Comment: Do you work with third-party projects? Is it possible for you to use binaries instead of source code? You could check class file version of a single .class-file in a .jar - if it's 52.0 then the class is compiled by Java 8.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov I am cloning the top 2000 git projects(by star) for my analysis, so I have the source code only.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete usage of java8 language features.

Comment: @AmeyaKetkar I think, if usage of git is not a requirement of your research, you could as well download top 2000 .jars from maven central repository, and process the class files. I know it doesn't exactly addresses your question, but personally I think it is a better approach

Comment: “*to decide that the particular project has migrated to Java8*”—well, a project can migrate to Java 8 without actively using any new language feature nor newer API. The only mandatory step of a migration is to compile against the new language and API and ensure that the code still works correctly. On the other hand, just inserting a lambda expression somewhere or accessing a new method, is not a proof of a completed migration.

Comment: @Holger what do u mean when you say that using let's say lambdas or collection#stream is not a proof of java8 migration?

Comment: Well, it’s only a proof that the particular source code has been touched since the introduction of Java 8, but it doesn’t prove that the entire project has been checked for Java 8 compatibility. Besides the possibility of having source code files in a different state of migration, the entire project might rely on a 3rd party library that is incompatible with Java 8. There’s also the possibility that only a few source code files exist to enable the use of a newer platform’s feature when present (i.e. these particular classes are loaded dynamically), while still targeting the older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see multiple approaches here, both source- and binaries-based, looking for Java 8 APIs and looking for Java 8 language features.

## Look for Java 8 APIs

#### Look for common Java 8 APIs in source code (simple)

You can parse the code and look for the APIs that first appeared in Java 8 - as you've suggested in your answer. The most commonly known features of Java 8 API are streams and `Optional` class, as well as `java.util.function` package. I would expect almost any project that migrated to Java 8 to use these features.

#### Look for all Java 8 APIs in source code (advanced)

To have 100% answer if a particular project uses Java 8 API or not, you would need to look not for some, but for all APIs that were added in Java 8. There are probably many ways to find that list, but there is a tool called [Sigtest](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/sigtest) created specifically to compare APIs of different versions of a product (in this case the product being Java itself).

#### Do the same in binaries

Probably a cheaper approach would be to use binaries rather than source files. All the external links are placed in the beginning of a .class-file, in a section called constant pool. There are tools that can help you to extract this data, e.g. [ClassDep](https://river.apache.org/doc/api/com/sun/jini/tool/ClassDep.html) (it is distributed as a part of Apache River, but you can use it standalone).

## Check language version

#### Check class file versions in binaries

For each language version there is a different version recorded in class files. For Java 7 that's 51.0, for Java 8 - 52.0, for Java 9 - 53.0. `javap` tool that comes with the JDK prints this version when launched with `-v` option.

#### Look for Java 8 language features

Since you're working with source code, I assume that your parser supports Java 8. If so, it will be able to identify Java 8 language structures, like lambdas and method references. The full (well, I assume it's full) list of Java 8 language features is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html).

## On accuracy of the results

The accuracy of each approach depends on what the question is. If it's "Does a project use Java 8 at all?" then no single approach will give 100% result. As Holger noted in his comments, there could be projects that partially migrated, that are only compiled for Java 8 and don't use any of its APIs, or that only use Java 8 APIs but are compiled for Java 7.

Question "Does a project use compilation with language level 8?" is best answered by class file version analysis - any class that uses lambdas will have version 52.0, but not vice versa.

Question "Does a project use Java 8 APIs?", obviously, requires analysis of references. I can only speculate on whether or not analysis of selected APIs is sufficient - a research like the one you're doing is what can give that answer.

Comment: Do you think detecting the usage of java8 language features will be accurate?

Comment: @AmeyaKetkar I've updated the answer to include a note about accuracy of approaches. As to analysis of selected portions of APIs like streams, I can't tell how accurate it will be. I can imagine a project that is not interested in streams and lambdas, but just wants to use `java.time` package, or maybe even some small security feature. I don't know how many such projects are out there (but it is interesting to find out!)

Comment: That's true.  .A lot of projects might have used only a small part of new Java API, I think I will have to run my analysis over all the new APIs provided.thanjs a lot.     If suppose there are two Java classes a.java and b.java . 'A' has used lambdas and 'b' has not used any java8 API , but both are compiled with java8 , will the two have 52.0 as their version?

Comment: @AmeyaKetkar In general, not necessarily. The product's build may be configured to compile files separately: `A.java` with `-target 1.8` option and `B.java` with `-target 1.7` option. Moreover, if `B.java` uses Java 8 API but does not use lambdas, it may still be compiled with `-target 1.7`.

Answer (score 3):

You can look for Java8 features.

Your best bet is to try to compile the code [yes, this is considered static analysis!] with a Java7 compiler, and a Java8 compiler, and see which one gives you the fewest compilation errors over the code base.  (You can generalize this to any of Java vN compilers easily enough).

If one compiler succeeds completely, and one the other does not, then your answer seems pretty clear.

If both compilers produce errors, you'll have to fall back on some other indicator (like, does it use Java8 features).

If the code compiles with both, you don't really know; it may be that some dark semantic corner of Java8 is critically used.     At this point, the only way to tell
is to run functionality regression tests, and choose the one that passes the most tests.

Comment: I have to analyse over 240 projects(5 tagged releases each). And these projects might be using ant/maven/gradle, so I will have to first get all the dependencies and then compile. Is there anything you could suggest to automate the downloading dependencies depending upon the build tool?Will writing a script be a viable option?

Comment: @AmeyaKetkar  Why can't you do the builds, simply replacing the path that leads to JavaC?

Comment: Thanks for the phrase “*which one gives you the fewest compilation errors*”; you got my +1. May the reader decide whether it is pessimism or realism…

Comment: @Holger: Every big system I ever met was a mess.   Some of it is real.  Some bits are not.   Thanks for your vote for realism :-}